# TinyMCE: How to enable the plugin to include referrer

Tags: tinymce

My image server has hotlink prevention enabled which only allows whitelisted referrer domains to display the image. I have my CMS(HTTPS) server which is running TinyMCE does not display the image when inserted from UI. The image becomes 403. I have set my Nginx server header `add_header 'Referrer-Policy' 'origin';` but no use. I don't think TinyMCE has header response enabled for SSL environment. Anyone know how to enable  Referrer-Policy in TinyMCE configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I need to add `<meta name="referrer" content="origin">`
to the iframe: https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/3.x/jscripts/tiny_mce/classes/Editor.js#L541

```
t.iframeHTML = s.doctype + '<html><head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><meta name="referrer" content="origin">';
```